# How to map names (Africa, Asia, North America, Latin America) into numbers (1,2,3,4,)?

Tags: r

I want to change (place) in the list to 1 Europe, 2 Asia, 3 Africa, 4 Latin America, and 5 North America. so I can have names on the plot rather than numbers.

What I have so far:

[image: What I have so far]

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take some time to read [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I didn't understand your question correctly at first. If you want to replace the values in a column with character strings and then use them in alphabetic order in ggplot you could try for example:

```
library(tidyverse)
last %>% 
  mutate(place = forcats::fct_recode(place %>% as.character(),
                                   'Europe' = '1',
                                   'Asia' = '2',
                                   'Africa' = '3',
                                   'Latin America' = '4',
                                   'North America' = '5') %>% as.character())
```

And then use the place in facet_grid. It should wrap them in alphabetic order. See this reproducable version of it:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(am = forcats::fct_recode(am %>% as.character(), 
                         'Africa' = '1', 
                         'Europe' = '0') %>% as.character()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~am)
```

Does this work as you intented?

Comment: i provide you with an image that may help to understand the problem, i'm new to R. However, in the third column contain (1,2,3,4,5) for all of the world countries displayed by alphabetic order.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question originally. I edited the answer so the names are in alphabetic order.

Comment: i have this list as follow: 
           V1      V2        V62          place
1       Aruba ABW  0.42078068     1
2 Afghanistan AFG  2.49078956     2
3      Angola AGO  3.31350733     3
4     Albania ALB -0.09197229     1
5     Andorra AND -0.40973567     1
6     Armenia ARM  0.19244221     2